# how to get a float using parseFloat(0.00)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a float of 0.00. The reason I need 0.00, is because I am going to be accumalating float values by adding. Hence starting with 0.00.
I tried

```
 var tmp ='0.00'
 tmp  = parseFloat(tmp.toString()).toFixed(2);
 totals = parseFloat(tmp)
```

tmp is 0.00 but totals is 0. How can I make total 0.00? I need it to stay as a float and not a string.
Thanks

Comment: JS doesn't actually have 'float' or 'int' types. They are all of type [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). It just happens to strip off the `.00` when you're displaying it. See [Be careful with JS numbers!](http://greweb.me/2013/01/be-careful-with-js-numbers/)

Comment: That makes no sense at all – _real_ numbers do not have just zeros behind a decimal point ever. Displaying a value without any decimals as `.00` is purely a matter of _formatting_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the string `tmp` variable and then when you need to add to it use:

```
tmp = (+tmp + 8).toFixed(2);
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/XpCQt/1/)

Or simply write a function to do that seeing that you'll have to do that many times:

```
function strAdd( tmp, num ) {
    return (+tmp + num).toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an integer type in javascript.  There is only `Number`, which is stored as a double precision floating point.  So to get a floating point value with 0.00, you need only to do this:

```
var tmp = 0;
```

Comment: I tried this first, however when I add 58.10 to it, it shows up as 58.1 instead of 58.10, which is what I want. The reason I want to keep it to decimal points is,i am checking if the total is 100.00. Not keeping 2 places may give me 99.99

Comment: @Mary: Then you would need to use `.toFixed(2)` (or some sort of rounding) when displaying the value.  Internally in JavaScript, you can't change how it's stored.

Comment: @Mary: That's not how numbers work in javascript.  It's always keeping as many places as it can.  When there are trailing zeroes after a decimal point, they are suppressed from display, but it's the same number.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tmp ='0.00'
tmp  = parseFloat(tmp.toString()).toFixed(2);
totals=parseFloat(tmp).toFixed(2);
alert(totals); //0.00
```

`parseFloat()` without `toFixed()` removes zeros after dot. So you need to add `toFixed()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is dynamic floatParser for those who need

```
function customParseFloat(number){
  if(isNaN(parseFloat(number)) === false){
    let toFixedLength = 0;
    let str = String(number);

    // You may add/remove seperator according to your needs
    [".", ","].forEach(seperator=>{
      let arr = str.split(seperator);
      if( arr.length === 2 ){
        toFixedLength = arr[1].length;
      }
    })

    return parseFloat(str).toFixed(toFixedLength);
  }

  return number; // Not a number, so you may throw exception or return number itself
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use parseFloat function in Javascript.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var a = parseFloat("10") + "<br>";
    var b = parseFloat("10.00") + "<br>";
    var c = parseFloat("10.33") + "<br>";
    var d = parseFloat("34 45 66") + "<br>";
    var e = parseFloat("   60   ") + "<br>";
    var f = parseFloat("40 years") + "<br>";
    var g = parseFloat("He was 40") + "<br>";

    var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```