# Convert whole number to one decimal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I got this issue.
I want to convert integer `71` (type `number`) to one decimal, meaning `71.0`

but I need it to stay of type `number`.
Searched and the only solution I found was to use `toFixed(1)` and then `parseFloat` on
the result, and that does returns a `number` but `71`, without the decimal.

```
const float = (num) => {
    let fixed = (num).toFixed(1)
    let float = parseFloat(fixed)
    
    return float
}

float(71)
```

How should I do it?

Comment: "*meaning 71.0 but I need it to stay of type number.*" not possible. Numbers in JavaScript do not have a format attached to them, `71` is *the same* as `71.0`, which is *the same* as `71.00`, etc. JS truncates unnecessary zeroes for display. If you want a specific format, you need a string.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. As a number, `71` and `71.0` are **exactly** the same.

Comment: A _bit_ more depth: the number type in JavaScript is a "[double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)" value. (That applies to all numbers, even those that appear to be integers.) `71` and `71.0` are the same in this format.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense, because an integer (whole number) will almost always equal its floating-point equivalent, unless there is a some odd precision behavior.

- `71 === 71.0`
- `71 === 71.00`
- ...
- `71 !== 71.000000001`

Did you want to truncate a floating number using precision?

```js
const truncateFloat = (n, p = 0) => parseFloat(n.toFixed(p));

// Truncate an irrational number (PI)
console.log(truncateFloat(Math.PI, 2) === 3.14) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `parseFloat(fixed)` and keep it as below

```
const float = (num) => {
    let fixed = (num).toFixed(2)
    //let float = parseFloat(fixed)
    
    return float
}

float(71)
```

use `toFixed(n)` where `n` is the number of 10th places after the decimal.

You have stated that you need to keep it as `number` at the end but the thing is, if the decimals are `0`, it will always round up to a whole number. So you may want to rather consider adding the `toFixed(n)` at the point of printing to the screen so they always print with that extra.

========= UPDATE

I just found a cleaner solution. consider the below with a link to the solution

```
const float = (num) => {
    tmp = '0.00';
    tmp = (+tmp + num).toFixed(2);
    
    return tmp
}

float(71)
```

reference: [how to get a float using parseFloat(0.00)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394467/how-to-get-a-float-using-parsefloat0-00)

Comment: I just updated my answer. am not sure why you want it to specifically remain a number cos at your point of calculation, you can always do a `parseInt(number)` `eg: parseInt(71)` and you still get a number for your calculation.

Comment: check out the next update. it's a way better solution. hope that helps